# Diskbased to in memory tables sql server 2016 ram requirement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables

I am planning to migrate my tables to memory optimized tables. Currently, I have a total of 250 gigabytes database size on disk. If I migrate this to in memory tables, how much physical RAM will I need?

Answer (score 3):

Start with the [Books Online page on estimating memory requirements for in-memory OLTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/estimate-memory-requirements-for-memory-optimized-tables). It goes into deep detail, and here's just a snippet:

> When there is an active workload, additional memory is needed to account for row versioning and various operations. How much memory is needed in practice depends on the workload, but **to be safe the recommendation is to start with two times the expected size of memory-optimized tables and indexes**, and observe what are the memory requirements in practice. The overhead for row versioning always depends on the characteristics of the workload - especially long-running transactions increase the overhead. For most workloads using larger databases (e.g., >100GB), overhead tends to be limited (25% or less).

Keep in mind that that's only for the in-memory OLTP data - not your query workspace, buffer pool for other objects, AG log caching, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The answer (of course) is "it depends". 
Part of what it depends on is:
 1. what other features SQL Server you might consider using. For instance, using the temporal feature with memory-optimized tables requires addtional memory, etc.
 2. if you will be adding additional indexes (SQL 2017 now supports hundreds of indexes per memory-optimized table). A singe nonclustered index on a memory-optimized table does not support both ascending and descending queries, so you might have to add more indexes than are required for your on-disk workload.
 3. if your current data/indexes use any form of compression, i.e. row/page/columnstore

Also, have you done a POC that proves your workload will benefit from migrating to memory-optimized tables?